# PHP Fatal error returned when creating a new Symfony3 Project

Tags: symfony

When creating a symfony3 project with `symfony new MyNewProject` it seems to download without problem but then gives the following error:

> Preparing project...
>
> PHP Warning:  require(/projects/MyNewProject/app/SymfonyRequirements.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/src/Symfony/Installer/DownloadCommand.php on line 256
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/projects/MyNewProject/app/SymfonyRequirements.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/src/Symfony/Installer/DownloadCommand.php on line 256

However, if I create a new Symfony project with the LTS version with:

```
symfony new MyNewProject lts
```

...then the project is created without error. The directory structure seems to be created and populated ok however I guess that there is an internal problem somewhere?

In addition, I have installed a fresh Ubuntu on another computer and Symfony3 installs without this error

Comment: Might try updating your symfony installer and composer.  For S3, the requirements file lives in the var directory.  Your error indicates some sort of installer problem.

Comment: have you update your installer? try with a `symfony self-update` and try again...

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013744/symfony-3-0-installation

Comment: Great thank you - I've flagged the question to point to the question @Matteo gave the link to - thanks!

Comment: Hi @Bendy you are welcome! consider to up-vote my answer if you consider it useful

Comment: Done! Thanks again :)