# Symfony installing first step -> Warning and Fatal Error

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I'm currently trying to install symfony on ubuntu.

Problem, after typing : 
`php symfony.phar new Symfony`
it returns me this :

> PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/SymfonyRequirements.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in phar:///opt/lampp/htdocs/symfony.phar/src/Symfony/Installer/DownloadCommand.php on line 264
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/SymfonyRequirements.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in phar:///opt/lampp/htdocs/symfony.phar/src/Symfony/Installer/DownloadCommand.php on line 264

I can't understand where can be the problem, and I couldn't find any solution on the internet.

Does one of you know where can be the problem ?

Thank you

Best regards

FabulousCo

Comment: I would download symfony.phar again.  Make sure you change the permissions as in the instructions.

Comment: Could you run  `php symfony.phar self-update` first? Sounds like you're using an older version. In newer versions of the Symfony Installer, more explicit error messages are displayed helping you identify the true problem.

Comment: Thank you very much it I had to delete everything and reinstall it !

Comment: You can also [use composer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#creating-a-symfony-application-with-composer). That tends to be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add the version you are trying to install.

```
>symfony new my_project_name 3.0.0
```

Please see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013744/symfony-3-0-installation).

Comment: Not necessarily, see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html)